# Rails 4: Delete on has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

Based on one of the examples in the Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) I wrote the following code:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments

  def vips
    patients.where(appointments: { vip: true })
  end

  def add_vip patient
    appointments.create(patient: patient, vip: true)
  end

  def delete_vip patient
    vips.delete(patient)
  end
end
```

The problem is that if I have a `physician` (an instance of Physician) and a `patient` and then do

```
physician.add_vip(patient)
physician.delete_vip(patient)
```

the `delete_vip` not only deletes the association but the instance itself.

How can I delete only the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association/record you want to delete is the **Appointment** not the **Patient**. You are creating an appointment in `add_vip` and should be removing an appointment in `delete_vip`.

```
# Deletes all appointments for that patient without destroying the patient itself.
def delete_vip patient
  appointments.where(patient: patient, vip: true).delete_all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way (not only):

```
def delete_vip patient
    Appointment.where(physician_id: self.id, patient_id: patient.id).first.destroy!
end
```